# Rules that see certain email address in the To field will then exclude them in the Sent folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have setup my outlook to always store a copy of the email before I send them out into the `Sent` folder.

However, is it possible to exclude certain email address inside the `To` field?

e.g. Suppose there is a rule that is configure that if a email that I put `jack123@abc.com` inside the `To` field, the rule will not store a copy of the email into the `Sent` folder. The outlook will just send the email out.

Or does other email client application (e.g. Thunderbird) able to perform such operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is to manage `Sent Items` through your own rule.  So turn off `Save Message I send to Sent Items folder` in the account settings.

Then create a new rule, in the Rules Wizard choose `Apply to Messages I send` in the `Start from Blank Rule` section.

Then first, you just want to create a rule that copies all messages to `Sent Items`.  Once you have this, and it works, you can add exceptions to this rule for those email addresses you don't want to keep.